# How to capture the exception details in case of any action failed in the Scope action in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have implemented Azure Logic App to execute my business flow. For exception handling, I used **Scope** action. But I want to capture exception details in case of any action failed in the **Scope**.

Sample logic app flow to handle the exceptions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**The `result()` function provides context about the results from all the actions in a scope.** *The `result()` function accepts a single parameter, which is the scope's name, and returns an array that contains all the action results from within that scope.* These action objects include the same attributes as the `actions()` object, such as the action's start time, end time, status, inputs, correlation IDs, and outputs. To send context for any actions that failed within a scope, you can easily pair a `@result()` expression with the `runAfter` property.

To run an action for each action in a scope that has a Failed result, and to filter the array of results down to the failed actions, you can pair a `@result()` expression with a Filter Array action and a For each loop. You can take the filtered result array and perform an action for each failure using the `For_each` loop.

Here's an example, followed by a detailed explanation, that sends an HTTP POST request with the response body for any actions that failed within the scope "`My_Scope`":

```
"Filter_array": {
   "type": "Query",
   "inputs": {
      "from": "@result('My_Scope')",
      "where": "@equals(item()['status'], 'Failed')"
   },
   "runAfter": {
      "My_Scope": [
         "Failed"
      ]
    }
},
"For_each": {
   "type": "foreach",
   "actions": {
      "Log_exception": {
         "type": "Http",
         "inputs": {
            "method": "POST",
            "body": "@item()['outputs']['body']",
            "headers": {
               "x-failed-action-name": "@item()['name']",
               "x-failed-tracking-id": "@item()['clientTrackingId']"
            },
            "uri": "http://requestb.in/"
         },
         "runAfter": {}
      }
   },
   "foreach": "@body('Filter_array')",
   "runAfter": {
      "Filter_array": [
         "Succeeded"
      ]
   }
}
```

*For more details about this suggestion, you can visit [Get context and results for failures in Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-exception-handling#get-context-and-results-for-failures)*